# Guide me to do This Timer Application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I will tell my idea. If the person enter his time of birth in this format "YYYY: MM: DD: HH:MM:SS"
 My application will display: Ur life timer is :"26:11:13:02:03:55"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? What problems are you having? Generally speaking, this is just arithmetic. You start on the right and subtract, "borrowing" from the next-highest place as necessary.

You will probably need to deal with leap years, so do a google search for "number of days between dates" to get a correct formula for that - it's not hard, but lots of people get it wrong on their first try.

Answer (score 1):

try this below url
http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

Comment: Yeah, no need at all for ASP.NET if JavaScript is used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5760752.html